# SQL Group By clause without aggregation

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a web app which allows a user to select columns to group by, as well as columns to order by (among other options such as different aggregations). I am having a hard time figuring out how to write the SQL for this, if no aggregations are selected. For instance, if a user selects to

SELECT * FROM EmployeeWorkLocation
GROUP BY Work Location, Department
ORDER BY Employee Number

the results from the following EmployeeWorkLocation example table:

| employee number | work location | department | client number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dallas | maintenance | 111 |
| 2 | Houston | maintenance | 222 |
| 3 | Dallas | sales | 111 |
| 4 | Houston | sales | 222 |
| 5 | Dallas | maintenance | 222 |
| 6 | Dallas | sales | 222 |

should return the following results:

| employee number | work location | department | client number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| --Work Location: Dallas |  |  |  |
| -----Department: Maintenance |  |  |  |
| 1 | Dallas | maintenance | 111 |
| 5 | Dallas | maintenance | 222 |
| -----Department: Sales |  |  |  |
| 3 | Dallas | sales | 111 |
| 6 | Dallas | sales | 222 |
| --Work Location: Houston |  |  |  |
| -----Department: Maintenance |  |  |  |
| 2 | Houston | maintenance | 222 |
| -----Department: Sales |  |  |  |
| 4 | Houston | sales | 222 |

I am not worried about the headers that are displayed in the results, as they are just there to show how I want to display the results.

I realize this is essentially just a sort that is occurring without any aggregations, but was wondering if this could be achieved using a GROUP BY clause, and what the SQL would look like.

Comment: Selecting all columns and only grouping by some without the rest being in some form of aggregation is technically not valid, except possibly if you are using MySql - please tag your RDBMS

Comment: And even though MySql will allow you to do it, please don't.  This looks like something that should be handled in a reporting tool.

Comment: Ans it's invalid in newer MySQL versions... (Unless in compatibility mode.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL`.

```
select employee_number, work_location, department, client_number from (

select distinct CONCAT('-- Work Location :', work_location) employee_number, 
work_location ord_work_location, '' ord_department, CAST(null AS varchar)
work_location, CAST(null AS varchar) department, CAST(null AS varchar)
client_number, 0 ords from your_table_name

UNION ALL
select distinct CONCAT('---- Department :', department), work_location 
ord_work_location, department ord_department, CAST(null AS varchar), 
CAST(null AS varchar), CAST(null AS varchar), 1 ords from your_table_name

UNION ALL
select CAST(employee_number AS varchar), work_location, department 
ord_department, work_location, department, CAST(client_number AS varchar),
2 ords from your_table_name

)a order by ord_work_location, ord_department, ords
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/551751/6)